# OnClick works for only one ImageButton

Tags: android, onclick

Ok, I have two ImageButtons and I set them up exactly the same, but only PLAY gets called with the onClick listener. If I click the other one it doesn't register at all that it was clicked. When I debug them it show that my findViewById is registering the object to the right view and everything. I still get a touchevent but the Close button doesn't show up in my OnClick method. Perhaps the xml file is playing a role in this bug, because I can't think of anything else that could be happening.

fragment code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playback_frag,  container, false);

    //BUTTONS
    close = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.x_close);
    play = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.play1);

    btnListener = new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.e("in btnListener", "howdy");
        }
    };

    close.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
    play.setOnClickListener(btnListener);


    return v;
}
```

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="166dp"
    android:background="#D8000000"
    >
    <!-- Start of title bar -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

            <LinearLayout 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:weightSum="1" 
            android:background="#CC33b5e5" >

         <TextView android:id="@+id/playback_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                   />



               <TextView android:id="@+id/playback_sample_rate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"           
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                   />

               <TextView android:id="@+id/playback_file_size"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"                       
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                   />

                  <ImageButton android:id="@+id/x_close"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                   />
               </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
     <!-- End of title bar -->

      <!--start of details -->
      <ScrollView 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height = "118dp"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:paddingTop="44dp"
          >
          <TextView android:id="@+id/playback_details"
              android:paddingRight="6dp"
              android:paddingLeft="6dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              />
      </ScrollView>


      <!--end of details -->


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        >
            <!-- Start of slider -->
           <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/sliderANDplay"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="32dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/play1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#80000000"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:scaleX=".80"
                        android:scaleY=".80"
                        android:src="@drawable/av_play" />

                    <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/slider1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:max="60"
                            android:progress="0"
                            android:secondaryProgress="0" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- End of slider -->

           <!-- Start of times -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:gravity="right|bottom"
                >


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/curr_pos1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:text="@string/init_time_curr"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="/"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:textSize="11sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/max_duration1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
                            android:text="@string/init_time_max"
                            android:textColor="#ffffff"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                </LinearLayout>
             <!-- End of times -->


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create two seperate onClickListeners (one for each button) or check which button has been pressed in the one listener that you are using.

```
btnListener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        if (v.getID == R.id.x_close)
          Log.e("in btnListener", "howdy");
        else if (v.getID == R.id. play1)
        // do something else
    }
};
```

Comment: right that's what I am planning on doing, but when I click the close button it doesn't even register in the onClick listener that it has been clicked.

Comment: if by individual listener you mean `implements OnClickListener` on the fragment then yes (and then doing `setOnClickListener(this);`)

Comment: No i meant using two differnet listeners. One for each button. play.new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.e("in btnListener", "howdy");
        }
    };

Comment: and close.new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Log.e("in btnListener", "howdy close");
        }
    };

Comment: I tried that too. That shouldn't matter anyway. It must be something else that I'm over looking. This is inside a fragment so I don't know if that matters?